# Filter json and create backbone model and collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, backbone-model, backbone.js-collections

I have a json file that i want to filter and create a collection of this filtered json.

How can i do this?

```
file.json
->Calculators
->Constants
->Contents
```

I want to filter the file.json and make a collection from Constants Object Items.

Is it posible to make this?

The problem i'm having is that I can't filter the json, only pass all the variables of all the json to the model.

I have read and searched here on stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in the parse method of your backbone collection:

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  parse:function(data){
    return data.Constants;
  }    

});
```

This will return only the part of your json your want to be loaded into your collection.

Edit to give you some basics after your comment:

Hopefully your data.Constants contains an array of objects you want to be loaded into your collection as models. Of course you will need a model:

```
var myModel = Backbone.model.extend({});
```

Then you link that model to your Collection:

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: myModel,

  url: 'path/to/your/file.json',

  parse:function(data){
    return data.Constants;
  }    

});
```

And you fetch your collection:

```
var c1 = new myCollection();
c1.fetch();
```

Comment: I get it, and on the parse function I add this constants to the collection? How can i make a collection?